# With 2 buttons at footer. right side button going outside page jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer

I want to have 2 buttons in the footer, one on the left side and the other on the right side.

With dataposition fixed, however right side button going little outside the page view.

Here is the code.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" class="ui-bar" style="height:30px"  data-position="fixed">       
    <a class="ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="approvetm">
            Approve
    </a>

    <a id="sendback" data-rel="popup"  data-theme="a"  class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Send Back</a> 
</div>
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong in above code.....?

Answer (score 1):

As per [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/footers/) footer is different than header in terms of buttons accommodation.

> The page footer is very similar to the header in terms of options and configuration. The primary difference is that the footer is designed to be less structured than the header to allow more flexibility, so the framework doesn't automatically reserve slots for buttons to the left or right as it does in headers

However, this can be fixed by overriding `ui-btn-right` style (*right position*).

```
.ui-footer .ui-btn-right { right: 35px !important }
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n49Gu/)**